# Etymology of 'pre-emptive'

Tags: etymology

*Empt* or *emptive* does not exist as a word, and I suppose never has.

***Pre-empt*** and ***pre-emptive*** according to the OED have their origin in Australian land deals of the late-eighteenth century, where certain individuals were given ***pre-emtive*** rights over others.

But why ***empt***? Does anyone know any more about the origins of ***pre-emptive***.

Comment: From *emption* 'purchase'. Follow the bread crumbs: http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=preemptive&searchmode=none

Answer (score 2):

emption (n.) 
late 15c., "purchase," from Latin emptionem (nominative emptio) "a buying, purchasing; thing bought," noun of action from past participle stem of emere "to buy"

Originally used to describe something being offered for purchase to a group or individual before being offered publicly.

Answer (score 2):

"Pre-emptive," as we know it, seems to come from the Latin verb **emption**-, emptio, from emptus (past participle of emere to buy). See the definition [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/emption).

[The wikipedia entry of Pre-emption right](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-emption_right) states that this usage comes from "A right to acquire existing property in preference to any other person... usually referred to as a right of first refusal." It seems as though "pre-emptive" began as just meaning "right to first refusal" and morphed into a more general "right to first action" as time went on.

Comment: Very good. I was not aware of *emptio* and *emere*. I now note the English word *emption* in the OED and the French verb *préempter*.